# How can I show the last opening period for each project in my project dimension hierarchy using MDX ( Tail function)?

Tags: mdx, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I have two attributes hierarchies  in my dimension [Dim Project]:

- Project Code
- Opening date

Project A  with 3 opening date : 2023-01-01 ,  2023-01-02  and  2023-01-03

Project B  with 2 opening date :  2023-01-02 ,  2023-01-04

MDX query :

------------

```
SELECT 
    [Dim Project].[Project Code].[Project Code].ALLMEMBERS
  * 
    [Dim Project].[Opening date].[Opening date].ALLMEMBERS ON 0
 ,[Measures].[Measure1] ON 1
FROM Mycube;
```

I want to show for every Project its last Opening Period.

**Project_Code  Opening_Period  Measure1**

---

Project A     2023-01-03        Measure1_1

Project B     2023-01-04         Measure1_2

How can write this in MDX.?  Thank you so much for your help!

I know that Tail function can help in this  case but how !

Answer (score 0):

`GENERATE` is a function that can iterate through members - following is not tested but might help:

```
SELECT 
  Generate
  (
    [Dim Project].[Project Code].[Project Code].MEMBERS
   ,
      [Dim Project].[Project Code].CurrentMember
    * 
      Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Dim Project].[Opening date].[Opening date].MEMBERS
         ,([Dim Project].[Project Code].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Measure1])
        )
      )
  ) ON 0
 ,[Measures].[Measure1] ON 1
FROM Mycube;
```

Testing similar logic against MS's sandpit cube Adventure Works it seems ok:

```
SELECT 
  Generate
  (
    [Product].[Category].[Category].members
   ,
      [Product].[Category].CurrentMember
    * 
      Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
         ,([Product].[Category].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Sales Amount])
        )
      )
  ) ON 1
 ,[Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 0
FROM  [Adventure Works];
```

[image]